# C++11 applies result_of on member function, failed, why?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, decltype, result-of

I've got the following code as an experiment:

```
int f1() { return 0; }

struct Bar {
    Bar() = delete;
    int f() { return 0; }
    int operator()() { return 1; }
};

int main()
{
    decltype(f1()) x = 3;//f1() is expression
    result_of<decltype(&f1)()>::type x1 = 3;//type+param
    result_of<Bar()>::type x3 = 3;//type+param
    decltype(declval<Bar>().f()) y = 4;//expression
    decltype((((Bar*)nullptr)->*(&Bar::f))()) z = 5;//expression

    result_of<decltype(std::mem_fn(&Bar::f))()>::type y2 = 3;//error!!!!!!
}
```

Everything is OK except the last `result_of`:
I was trying to get the return type of `Bar::f`, using `result_of`.

Why it failed, and how to correct it?

Comment: It's a member function, it requires an implicit object parameter, i.e., `result_of<decltype(std::mem_fn(&Bar::f))(Bar)>::type y2`

Comment: Thanks, it works, but seems "result_of<decltype(std::mem_fn(&Bar::f))(Bar*)>::type y2 = 3;" can also pass compilation. Which is correct, why BAR* can still be given to this mem_fn?

Comment: It makes no difference whether you use a pointer or a reference type. What matters here is the value-category and cv-qualification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *unspecified* return type of `mem_fn`:

```
template <class R, class T>
unspecified mem_fn(R T::* pm) noexcept;
```

is defined in terms of `INVOKE` [[func.memfn]/p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.memfn#1):

> <sup>1</sup> *Returns*: A simple call wrapper ([[func.def]](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.def)) `fn` such that the expression `fn(t, a2, ..., aN)` is equivalent to `INVOKE(pm, t, a2, ..., aN)` ([[func.require]](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.require)).

where the definition of `INVOKE` includes the following two bullets [[func.require]/p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.require#1):

> Define `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` as follows:
>
> — `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `is_base_of<T, decay_t<decltype(t1)>>::value` is `true`;
>
> — `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` does not satisfy the previous two items;

That is, the first argument of what `mem_fn` returns must be the type of the implicit object parameter (`t1`), either a reference or a pointer, e.g.:

```
std::result_of<decltype(std::mem_fn(&Bar::f))(Bar&)>::type y2;
//                                            ~~~^

std::result_of<decltype(std::mem_fn(&Bar::f))(Bar*)>::type y2;
//                                            ~~~^
```

You could also remove `std::mem_fn` altogether:

```
std::result_of<decltype(&Bar::f)(Bar*)>::type y2;
```